# "angular-file-upload" - read directive's options in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using "angular-file-upload" from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload. 
In my html I have ...

```
<div ng-controller="UploadCtrl" uploader="uploader" options="{recordid:model.id}">
```

From the documentation I read...

> The attribute options may be a {FileItem} options or custom
>   properties.

So far so good - but how can I retrieve the options object? The most I could find out was this when I do a console.log() on the uploader object:

```
//console output from console.log(uploader)
uploader.filters[0].name='recordid';
uploader.filters[0].fn=function(a) {...}
```

This is my controller

```
app.controller('UploadCtrl2', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'FileUploader', 'Store',
function ($rootScope, $scope, FileUploader, Store) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'upload.php'
        formData:[]
    });

    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item, options) {
        console.log(uploader);
    };

    (...)
});
```

Comment: Did you try checking the "options" parameter of the onBeforeUploadItem callback ?

Comment: @Sami Triki: yes, it returns undefined

Comment: Alright, now try accessing item.recordid ? Same thing, on the onBeforeUploadItem callback

Comment: when I do console.log(item) I get an object named "i" with multiple properties like _file, _xhr, progress, uploader, etc. - but no recordid